# Older SQLite DB + BOOL + DB Browser Weirdness

Tags: c#, sqlite

I took over work on a C# project that was using a SQLite DB that was created at least 3 years ago. The previous developer was using some plugin for FireFox to manage the DB.

When I took over I installed DB Browser and opened the DB to add some new fields. When I choose modify table I see a number of fields of type
BOOL When I create new fields BOOL Is not an option. I have read where SQLite doesn’t have native BOOL like t-sql for example and that is fine. I can easily keep my bool values as int 1 or 0.

1) But why does DB Browser show me BOOL as the type of some existing fields?

2) And why does this C# work with these BOOL fields?
rs is a record set into this SQLite table and EnableNFCTools is one of the fields that is showing as the BOOL Type. This code is correctly setting the enableNFCTools variable from the DB value.

```
bool.TryParse(string.Format("{0}", rs["EnableNFCTools"]), out enableNFCTools);
```

The codes above doesn’t work with the new INTEGER fields I added and now I have to use something like this to correctly get the settings from these INTEGER fields.

```
if ((long)rs["BadgePrintingEnabled"] == 1)
 badgePrintingEnabled = true;
else
 badgePrintingEnabled = false;
```

Again, if there really isn’t a BOOL type then why does DB Browser show BOOL for some of the existing fields in this at least three year old DB?
And why does C# bool handling of these BOOL Types work?

Comment: Required reading: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html Basically, you can use pretty much anything as a column type in a table definition and sqlite will try to map it to a native type when storing values in that column. `BOOL` is treated as if you'd used `NUMERIC`, and the convention is indeed to use 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: Thanks for the information but it doesn't answer either of my two questions. 1) Why is the DB Browser GUI showing me BOOL as the type for some fields and why can't I create new fields in the db Browse's GUI with type BOOL. 2) Why do the existing BOOL field in this DB act like a true bool db value in c# if there is not bool type? INTEGER and NUMERIC have to be handled like non bool types to correctly t read them from the DB. The existing fields that are showing BOOL do work as a BOOL type in converting to a C# variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SQLite DOES have a BOOL type and it works like a true DB type of BOOL (in at least my C# code).

If you use Create Table you can set the type to BOOL and
DB Browser WILL show the type as BOOL but you can’t change any existing columns to Type BOOL.

AND in your C# code you have to handle this BOOL column from the DB
As a BOOL type NOT as an INTERGER type.

And NUMERIC -does not- act like a BOOL type.
When I try to set a C# variable from a NUMERIC field, neither way shown above to get the value out of the database works.

Under the hood, SQLite is doing something with the BOOL type we do not completely understand here.

Using GetType().ToString() I found that these SQLite types show up in C# as these types:
Debug.Write(rs["A Field of The Type To Check"].GetType().ToString());

```
SQLite Type / C# GetType().ToString()
------------------------------------
NUMERIC = System.Decimal
INTEGER = System.Int64
BOOL = System.Boolean
```

Yes there really is a BOOL type in SQlite,
or at least acts like BOOL in C#...